# Optimizing Canvas animation

Tags: silverlight, xaml, animation

In my XAML UI, I have 4 canvas panels.
At a time only one is visible and others are collapsed.
I am using transform to have horizontal sliding effect while displaying a canvas.

I have two options to do this:

option1:

When I want to goto a Canvas, I move all other 3 canvases out of screen because i dont know which one is currently active. Advantage of this is I have only 4 animations, one for each canvas.

option2:

I define new animation for going to a particular canvas from another particular canvas. In this case I do not need to move all three canvases but only one. But then I need to create12 animations, 3 for each canvas.

I think option 1 is memory efficient since only 4 animation instances are there but there is CPU performance overhead.

Option 2 is CPU efficient but causes memory overhead due to 12 animation instances.

Which option should i prefer?

Thanks,
Tushar

Answer (score 3):

Just out of interest, have you considered using the `VisualStateManager`?  By defining an 'OnScreen' and 'OffScreen' `VisualState` via a style, and applying that to each of the Canvases, you would only have to code it once, let the `VisualStateManager` call the whichever animation is appropriate by using `VisualStateManager.GoToState()` which means you don't need 12 animation instances, and you don't need to call 4 animations every state change.  Best of both worlds?
If you need more information, I can provide some example code shortly.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you've thought through the implications of each approach rather well. Unfortunately, only you can answer the question that you've posed. If memory is of concern to your application, then you should go with option 1. But if your application is sensitive to being CPU-bound, then you should go with option 2.

I know that's largely a non-answer ... but as it always is with performance, you should do some profiling and testing of both approaches. You may find that the relative benefits or drawbacks of both approaches is negligible, in which case you should go with whatever option is more maintainable and easier for you to code (probably option 1) :-)